# Assembly load on iis

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I created WebApplication in local machine. It works good. But when I deploy this project to IIS i have a problem. 
I understand that doing bad, but in `ControllerInstaller` I write this:

```
container.Register(       
          Classes
         .FromAssembly(Assembly
         .LoadFrom(@"D:\Shevtsov\HarbaHabr\Habra.Web\bin\Habra.Web.dll"))
         .BasedOn<IController>()
         .LifestyleTransient());
```

It is clear that this path on the server it will not work... 
Please tell me, how path I must to write here?

P.S. `ControllerInstaller` in assembly `Habra.ServiceLocation`.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: What is `ControllerInstaller`?  Please tag *which* IOC container you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath.aspx) method which returns the absolute path to a file on the server given a relative path starting from the root of the web application denoted by `~/`:

```
container
    .Register(       
        Classes
            .FromAssembly(
                Assembly
                    .LoadFrom(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/bin/Habra.Web.dll"))
            )
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .LifestyleTransient()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC 4 (or above), I recommend using the [PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx), then simply create a class as below in your `Hara.Web` assembly:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Registration), "Register")]

public class Registration
{
   public static void Register()
   {
     var container = ...;
     container.Register(       
       Classes
       .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
       .BasedOn<IController>()
       .LifestyleTransient());
   }
}
```

Phill Hacck has a very good blog post about using this attribute [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx).